# Are Resource Dictionary Colors, Styles and Templates created for a Xamarin Forms application declared the same way for a Win UI 3 application

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, winui-3

Are Resource Dictionaries created for use in a Xamarin Forms application usable in a Win UI 3 application, or are there major syntactical differences in the way Colors, Styles and Templates are declared for each?

Comment: I don't know re those specific topics, but here is [one person's attempt to describe the various xaml implementations](https://github.com/gatewayprogrammingschool/XAML-Standardization). Unfortunately, that was two years ago, and didn't get very far. Maybe someone has done a more recent / more complete comparison.

Comment: Yes , the xaml syntax is almost the same , you can try this in the sample https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/ResourceManagement/cs-winui/winui_desktop_packaged_app .